# How do we know that the Megillah reader in shul must accommodate a cheresh?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Shulchan Aruch says that a "cherish" is exempt from the mitzvah of hearing the Megillah. My deaf son was surprised to read this statement, and he feels sorely left out of enjoying a beautiful holiday. He says that he "heard" (O.K., he hears with his cochlear implants on, even though he is still deaf) that somewhere in the Megillah, it implies that the deaf MUST be accommodated. He can't recall where that source is. Does anyone know?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I think *Esther* [4:14](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3304.htm#14) and [7:4](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3307.htm#4) could be used to good effect here.

Comment: @Fred and doesn't it say that _Mordochay_ left Israel with the _cheresh_? Maybe we can use that, too....

Comment: @msh210 Well, מרדכי בלשן מספר, "Mordechai speaks with his tongue" ([*Ezra* 2:2](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt35a02.htm#2)).

Answer (score 4):

Ah! I found it!!!

It's the very 1st verse....

ויהי בימי אחשורוש WHO???? אחשורוש !

Comment: That proves that אחשורוש was deaf.

Comment: @GershonGold - That assumption may lead to recursion. If אחשורוש had read the Megillah, maybe he would have done things, differently.

Comment: He was deaf therefore there was no problem.